# List - how to find item by reference?

Tags: c#, list, class

I want to make something like this:

```
class BaseClass
{
    private List<MyClass> list;

    private void addData()
    {
        list.Add(new MyClass(this));
    }

    public void removeData(MyClass data)
    {
        list.Remove(data);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private BaseClass baseClass;

    public MyClass(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        this.baseClass = baseClass;

        // DO SOMETHING

        calculationDone();
    }

    private void calculationDone()
    {
        baseClass.removeData(this);
    }
}
```

My problem is that `list.Remove()` returns false and item is not removed from the list. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a timing problem.

You are calling `calculationDone()` from the constructor, *before* the instance could have been assigned to the list in the calling method.

Only when the constructor (and the calculation) is done is the item added to the list.

```
public MyClass(BaseClass baseClass)
{
    this.baseClass = baseClass;

    // DO SOMETHING

    calculationDone();
}
```

The sequence in your code is:

- addData()

  - constructor of X

    - calculationDone
    - list.Remove(X)   // fails, X not found
  - List.Add(X)

The moral here is not to put all work (entire lifetime) of an object in the constructor. When you  split the constructor and the calculation it becomes:

```
private void addData()
{
    var temp =new MyClass(this); 
    list.Add(temp);
    temp.DoCalculations();  // includes calculationDone()
}
```

and this will work as expected.

Comment: list.add is inside *private* method of a BaseClass, and it's not clear where it's called.

Comment: @tigran - why would that matter?

Comment: "before the instance could have been assigned to the list in the calling method." What about the mysterious "// DO SOMETHING" block? I assume it's added from there, it makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: You say that the problem is that Remove is called before Add (basically), but the thing is that it's not clear *when* actually add is called, cause it can be called inside some code present in  // DO SOMETHING. So, imo, the problem here is not call sequence, but in entire architecture. Also from the question provided  it's missleading and unclear.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - totally irrelevant, all happening inside the ctor.

Comment: @Tigran - `List.Add()` is called in `BaseClass.addData()`. It's all in the question, no missing pieces.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: so let's come back to my first comment: the BaseClass.addData() is *private*, you can not possibly call it from outside of it, and there is no evidence in the question of any other method that would call it in some way. That's what I mean in my first comment.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ah, I see - and the constructor is called from `addData`, not from some place outside the code. Makes sense (I mean, the explanation makes sense, not the code ;-)

Comment: @Tigran - Ok, of course something has to call `addData()` . But how/where is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: well, considering that yo are talking about sequence of calls, *it is relevant* instead. But considering that your answer was accepted, means that you nailed it, even if I still have no idea how :)

Comment: @tigran - just imagine another method in BaseClass that sets the ball rolling.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: yes, I understand :) I mean, looking on the same code I saw different things, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Because`this` in one class is different from `this` in another.

```
class BaseClass
{
  ....
   list.Add(new MyClass(this)); //new MyClass created and pushed on the list 
  ...
}
```

and inside `MyClass`

```
class MyClass  {
   private void calculationDone()
   {
     baseClass.removeData(this); //this is not inside the list
   }
}
```

In other words: you have to create an association between your `MyClass` objects and `BaseClass`, so you may reach correct *instance* of `MyClass`.

Comment: But both uses match the right parameters and shouldbe the right values.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: this, called inside MyClass easily may not be that one present inside the list, and it's not in case of OP (at least according to the behavior described in the question)

Comment: `this` is the same in the context of inheritance.

Comment: @James: there is no inheritance here, only encapsulation.

Comment: @Tigran - and there is no problem with the use of `this` here.

Comment: @Tigran eek, your correct `BaseClass` threw me off. However, that still isn't what the problem is. From what I can see the reference is lost at `list.Add(new MyClass(this))`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: if you create MyClass separately it can, as it's absolutely not clear how add is done actually. I mean all our discussions are lack of some terrain, as there is no clear evidence of what happening in *architecture* of OP's app. I, personally, think that *there is* a problem with instances. Especially note the fact that OP says: " and item is not removed from the list.". So there are items in the list, but they just not removed as he would expect, so, imo, it's *clearly* instances mess issue.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of events when `addData` is called is:

1. `new MyClass(this)` is called which
2. Executes the `MyClass(baseClass)` constructor which
3. Calls the `calculationDone` method which
4. Tries to remove the object from the base's list
5. The removal fails because the object is not added
6. The constructor finishes
7. The item is added to the list.

So, you are removing the `MyClass` instance from the list, before it's even added. I would suggest avoiding of any heavy lifting in the constructor, and off-loading that to a `Execute` (or similarly named) method.